# How to use iBeacon to broadcast an advertisement?

Tags: broadcast, ads

As the title, can anyone tell me this (maybe very simple but I really stuck in this).
Thank very much!

Comment: What are you stuck on exactly? Helps us help you if you can be more specific.

Comment: Thank you. I am using android to do some research about iBeacon. I have a iBeacon and I know some apps from Google play store that can recognize the near iBeacon. But I still unclear about how to make a advertisement and use iBeacon to broadcast it. Besides, I don't know android apps can configure iBeacon or not? if can, what library I can use to write code to configure iBeacon. (Plz remember that this is only in android, I don't work with iOS)

Answer (score 1):

Beacons can't broadcast ads. All they can broadcast is their location. So you need your android app to recognise the location broadcast by a specific beacon (e.g. the bakery store) and send an ad for (e.g.) a free muffin. Hope that helps! Check Github for more beacon android info.

Comment: Not even their location, really. You just assume that since your app spots the beacon, it must be nearby. It would transmit "I'm the bakery store iBeacon" (roughly speaking), your app has to do the rest. iOS for example would tell you it's right there, close, a bit further, or just detectable.